# How do I find my Company or App information in the online portals?

Tags: iphone, app-store, cordova

Over the past few hours it feels like I've created App names, App ids, company name and all the rest with Apple and now I can't remember what's what.

I need to fill in the following for bundle identifier for my .plist file in xcode4:

```
com.mycompanyname.myappname
```

**Where can i find this info on my account itunesconnect.apple.com?**

---

**Update:**

The bit I'm having trouble with is finding my Company Name

Comment: See the end of my answer for where your company name is.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to find a list of existing bundle ID's, [click here to go to the iOS Provisioning Portal](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action). You will be prompted to log in.

Once you are logged in, look for the sidebar:

[image]

Then, click on "App IDs" and scroll down.

---

If you're looking for an App ID that you've set up for a specific app in the iTunes Connect portal, follow these steps:

First of all, [log in to iTunes Connect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com).

Next, click on "Manage Your Applications".

[image: Manage Applications in iTunes Connect]

You will see a list of your apps. Click on the one whose details you want to see.

[image: Managing Nippon in iTunes Connect]

You will t*hen see your apps details as well as some buttons. Your information should be in the top left corner, like so:

[image: Nippon is Ready for Sale]

---

To find your Company Name, you should simply log into iTunes Connect. It will be in the top right corner.

[image: Company Name in iTunes Connect]

Comment: Thanks Moshe, yeah this is where i was looking. Somehow, in !Identifiers" under Bundle Id i just have "iosapp" rather than `.com...`

Comment: Do you think I'm ok with "iosapp" as my Bundle ID ?